# Difference between '42..toFixed(3)' and '-42..toFixed(3)'?

Tags: javascript

According to this [post](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md),

```
 42..toFixed( 3 );   // "42.000"
```

The above code is valid, `42..toFixed(3)` works because the first `.` is part of the number and the second `.` is the property operator.

However, the results of `-42..toFixed( 3 );` and `-42 .toFixed(3)` are `-42` under Chrome, which is different with the positive number. Why? I want to know how does the engine handle the above codes?

Comment: Use `(-42).toFixed(3)` instead of `-(42..toFixed(3))`. (The parentheses make it a bit more obvious what you're doing)

Answer (score 2):

```
(42.).toFixed(3) // Results 42.000
(-42.).toFixed( 3 ); // Results -42.000
```

Use Parentheses to make yourself and the programming clear about what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but my guess is that the `.toFixed` call has priority over `-` sign, and that leads to the following flow:

1. execution of 42..toFixed(3), which results '42.000'
2. applying `-` to the result of step 1, i.e. -'42.000', which, obviously, results -42